# Concatenate 2 integers to an integer MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a scraped some sports data, which contains an id field that ideally I'd like to use as Mongo's "_id". It's event based data and the IDs are meant to be unique however there is a few cases where they are not. However each entry also has a match id value, which is unique. There is never duplicated event IDs for the same match id. I was looking for a way to concatenate the two fields to create a unique id value that I could then use as the "_id" but this doesn't seem possible. I tried using the $concat operation with $tostring however this results in values such as 54821.4e+09
For example, a document with match id 3181621 and event id 1339018347 using

```
{$project:{"new_id":{$concat:[{"$toString":"$matchId"},"",{"$toString":"$id"}]}}}
```

results in "new_id" : "3181621.33902e+09", when I would want it to be 31816211339018347

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Is this a one-time shot, i.e. you want to permanently change a doc like `{evid: 12345678, matchid: 23456789}` into `{_id: 1234567823456789}`?  And is the resulting `_id` a true int or now can it be treated as a string int, e.g. `{_id: "1234567823456789"}`